# How to turn two lists of unequal lengths into coordinates?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following two lists;

```
a = {-1.8, -1.6, -1.4, -1.2, -1., -0.7, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0.4, 
    0.6, 0.8, 1., 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8}
b = {.2, .4, .6, .8, 1., 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8}
```

I want to turn this into coordinate points where each ai value is matched to each bi. Essentially (-1.8,.2),....,(-1.8,1.8) would be the first 9 points and it would create points for all 19 values of a.

Comment: `Outer[List, a, b] // Flatten[#, 1] &`

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps `Tuples[{a, b}]`?

See [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html).

Comment: Would have to `Partition` that if OP wanted 19 separate lists.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Yep, and we'd have to `Flatten` yours if the OP doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Distribute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html):

```
Distribute[{a, b}, List]
```

and [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
Join @@ (Thread[{#, b}] & /@ a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that

```
Transpose[{ConstantArray[#, 9], b}] & /@ a
```